# Does a phrase, "something authentic" make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm a non-native English speaker recently trying to launch my own company named "Origin Authentic"

And I'm also planning to launch a brand named "Honey Authentic" which is to be a name of a dessert cafe.

Does this "something authentic" series make sense to you? If not, does it make you feel weird when is heard at least?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: "something authentic" makes perfect sense. "Noun Authentic" is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, English naturally puts the adjective before the noun. If you want to put the adjective after the noun, you would have to make it sound exotic (e.g. "Honey Authentique"). Although, oddly enough, "Origin Authentic" sounds fine.

Comment: Oh my, I love the one you've suggested, "Honey Authentique"

Thank you for the good advice!

Comment: Not being correct, grammatical English makes very little difference to its suitability as a brand name

Comment: @JakeKang There are English adjectives that can function postpositively, but it is a very restricted set. Some examples from [CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468) (p. 445):

Comment: *the only day **suitable**, years **past**, proof **positive**, matters **financial**, all things **Irish**,  the people **present**, the cars **involved**, the students **concerned**, the city **proper**, the heir **apparent**, the body **politic**, the president **elect**, the devil **incarnate**, the poet **laureate**, a notary **public**, the house currently **ablaze**, all people now **alive**, the ones **asleep***.